# Dimension of the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $W = \{ p(x) :\int_{0}^{3}p(x)dx = 0,\;\; p'(3) = 0\}$ be a subspace of the real polynomials of degree $\leq 15$. What is the dimension of $W$?
I know that the answer is 14 but how may I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

The space $\mathbb{R}_{\leqslant15}[x]$ of all polynomials whose degree is $\leqslant15$ has dimension $16$. And your space is the intersection of the kernels of $2$ linear forms defined there. Since the linear forms are linearly independent (none of them is a multiple of the other one), $\dim W=16-1-1=14$.